# Best practices to messages feedback after POST in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm tring to find a good approach to feedback messages after a POST.

for example, I have these methods

```
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        Model model = getModel(id);           

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(Model model)
    {

        Result result = saveModel(result)

        if (Result.Status != Status.SUCCESS)
        {
            ...
        }
        else if(Result.Status != Status.FAILURE)
        {
            ...
        }else
        {
            ...
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

and Result class has a message property

```
        public class Result
        {
           ...
           public string Message{get;set;}
        }
```

So, When I call .../Controller/Index/1 my index view is shown and this view has an submit button that call Save Action, but if something goes wrong on business layer, I would like to present error/warning message.

so, the doult is What is the best approach to solve this situation?

I have read some article that recommend TempData, others recommend ViewData, to transfer the message to Index View.

Comment: If you want to persist the data between across the request, you must use TempData. ViewBag wont work if you are redirecting to another action...

Comment: `TempData` for redirects, `ViewBag` for same page.

Answer (score 6):

Let me share an example of a ChangePassword action of one project that I developed:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && _userService.ChangePassword(model.Password, model.NewPassword))
        ViewBag.SuccessMessage = UI.PasswordChanged;
    else
        ModelState.AddModelError("Password", ErrorMessages.InvalidPassword);
    return View(model);
}
```

Just remember that ViewBag wont work if you are redirecting to another action. You must use TempData if you want to persist the information across one request.

Answer (score 2):

For failures you should use

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "The error message");
```

since it will automatically be picked up by `Html.ValidationSummary(true)` (which is automatically added to all views)

For notifications you can use either `TempData` or the `ViewBag`.

I however discourage you from redirecting for everything. Instead give the user a chance to correct any errors (even if it's the business layer which generates them). Use something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Model model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);


    Result result = saveModel(result)
    if (Result.Status == Status.SUCCESS)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    if (Result.Status != Status.FAILURE)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Ooops, failed");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Some other error");
    }

    return View(model)
}
```